# Why Iterator of Series to Iterator of Series pandasUDF (PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER) when Series to Series (PandasUDFType.SCALAR) is available?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There are different kinds of pandasUDFType depending upon the input and the output type of the function.

There is:

series to series `PandasUDFType.SCALAR`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

@pandas_udf('long', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def pandas_plus_one(v):
    return v + 1

spark.range(10).select(pandas_plus_one("id")).show()
```

And there is also Iterator of Series to Iterator of Series `PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

@pandas_udf('long', PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER)
def pandas_plus_one(iterator):
    return map(lambda s: s + 1, iterator)

spark.range(10).select(pandas_plus_one("id")).show()
```

Can you please give me a simple usecase that cannot be solved by series to series `PandasUDFType.SCALAR` and can be solved by Iterator of Series to Iterator of Series `PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER`. I cannot seem to understand what is the need to have one while the other is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#iterator-of-series-to-iterator-of-series) and [Databricks docs](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html#iterator-of-series-to-iterator-of-series-udf), these two types of Pandas UDFs are quite similar but differ in some aspects. In addition to input and output type differences, `Iterator of Series to Iterator of Series UDF` can only take a single column as input whereas `Scalar UDF` can take multiple input columns. To make Iterator UDF takes multiple spark columns, you'll need to use [Iterator of multiple Series to Iterator of Series UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#iterator-of-multiple-series-to-iterator-of-series) which is basically the same as `Iterator of Series to Iterator of Series UDF` but takes an iterator of a **tuple** of `p.Series` as parameter.

Iterator UDFs [are said useful](https://www.iteblog.com/ppt/sparkaisummit-north-america-2020-iteblog/pandas-udf-and-python-type-hint-in-apache-spark-30-iteblog.com.pdf#page=32) when:

- You need to pre-fetch the input iterator

```
@pandas_udf("long") 
def do_something(iterator: Iterator[pd.Series]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]: 
    threading.Thread(consume, args=(iterator, q)) # prefetch the iterator 
    for s in q: 
        yield func(s)
```

- You need to do some expensive state initialization before processing each batch:

```
@pandas_udf("long") 
def do_something(iterator: Iterator[pd.Series]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]: 
    s = some_initialization() # initialize states
    for x in iterator: 
        yield func(x, s) # use the state for the whole iterator
```

However, there is this citation from the docs which makes some confusion as it sates that internally it works identically as Series to Series:

> It is also useful when the UDF execution requires initializing some
> states **although internally it works identically as Series to Series**
> **case**

Comment: I still did not understand the difference. What if I would like to create a pandas udf whose signature is like the typical signature of many Spark SQL functions, with the *args argument like `myfunction(*cols)` ?